# DQL using LibPhoneNumber

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, libphonenumber

I have a LibPhoneNumber object `$phone` I pass to a repository method. In my repository method I have:

```
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p, m FROM AppBundle:Phone p JOIN p.member m WHERE p.phoneNumber = :phone AND m.allowFind = TRUE'
        )
        ->setParameter("phone", $phone)
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

The problem is the query that is being generated and run literally inserts 'Object(libphonenumber\PhoneNumber)'

```
WHERE p0_.phone_number = 'Object(libphonenumber\\PhoneNumber)' AND m1_.allow_find = 1
```

if I use the default repository method `findOneByPhoneNumber($phone)` it correctly converts the phone number into the format in which it is stored in the database `+14565551212`

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out... Looks like for some reason I need to make the conversion manually while for some reason the built in findOneByxxxxx() method does it automatically some how. Maybe someone could comment on that?

Either way, I made the conversion manually by doing:

```
    $phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
    $number = $phoneNumberUtil->format($phone, \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat::E164);
```

and then passing `$number` into the `setParameter("phone". $number)` method instead of `$phone` which was the object.